# Behavior with Kotlin Higher-Order Functions and Single-method interfaces?

Tags: lambda, rx-java, kotlin, rx-kotlin

I was having some issues using RxJava and Kotlin earlier. I made some interesting discoveries which I'm still puzzled about.

There is the simple `Func1` interface in RxJava

```
public interface Func1<T, R> extends Function {
    R call(T t);
}
```

I was trying to add an extension method to an `Observable`, also an RxJava class. This would collect the emissions into a Google Guava `ImmutableListMulitmap` using a `Func1` to map the key off each item.

```
fun <K,T> Observable<T>.toImmutableListMultimap(keyMapper: Func1<T, K>): Observable<ImmutableListMultimap<K,T>> {
    return this.collect({ ImmutableListMultimap.builder<K,T>()},{ b, t -> b.put(keyMapper.call(t), t)}).map { it.build() }
}
```

When I tried to invoke this extension method I could not get it to compile, and it was not understanding the lambda expression at all.

```
ScheduledItem.all.flatMap { it.rebuildSoftTransactions }
.toImmutableListMultimap { it.id /*compile error */ } .cache()
```

However, the strangest thing happened when I modified the extension method to use the [function type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-types).

```
fun <K,T> Observable<T>.toImmutableListMultimap(keyMapper: (T) -> K): Observable<ImmutableListMultimap<K,T>> {
    return this.collect({ ImmutableListMultimap.builder<K,T>()},{ b, t -> b.put(keyMapper(t), t)}).map { it.build() }
}
```

And then everything compiled fine. But this is what puzzled me: How come it did not infer the lambda onto the interface? When I use the standard `map()` method on the `Observable` it infers the lambda just fine using the curly bracket `{ }` syntax. But why does it not work for my extension method above?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The SAM conversion (converting a lambda into a function type) currently works only for methods written in Java. Kotlin has proper function types, so there is no need for SAM conversion - you can declare the parameter as a function type directly (which works, as you have observed).

`Observable.map()` is written in Java, so the SAM conversion is applied. Your extension function is written in Kotlin, so it's not.